# Shipping information in checkout/onepage/ not coming from app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Progress.php

Tags: magento-1.7, onepage-checkout, shipping-methods

I'm trying to return a custom string from the function that returns the shipping method (can be seen here - https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHtKw.jpg)

I have overridden the core functionality and created app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Progress.php and I have returned custom strings in the functions getShippingMethod() and getShippingDescription() but none are shown in the onepage checkout process.

As a test, I tried doing the return on getShippingMethod() and getShippingDescription() in the core file but that shows no results either.

My question is, how do I change the text "Please select one of the following options: - Send Package Express" that you see in the image link I have posted?

Comment: Have you tried translation?  Enable template hints, find the relevant template and see if the text passes through translation (the `__()` method).  If it does you don't need to rewrite any classes.